# How can these generic classes be distinct between different divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm creating a notification system for a game to work similar to how notifications might work in a phone.

The notifications are all created initially, hidden, and later the game is supposed to "activate" certain ones from in-game triggers.

I'm running into problems when trying to keep the notifications separate in terms of their classes. Each notification starts off as a small rectangular box with only the title visible. Upon clicking, the notification expands and the description becomes visible.

Right now, clicking a notification does expand that notification and display its notification, but any other notifications also show their descriptions as well.

Example code:

```
var NotificationItems = new Array();

scope.registerNotification = function(title, description)
{

    //add it to the array
    NotificationItems.push(new scope.Application(title, description));

    var $NotificationContainer = $("#NotificationContainer");
    $NotificationContainer.append('<div class="Notification" title="'+title+'"></div>');
    var $thisNotification = $NotificationContainer.children('.Notification[title='+title+']');
    $thisNotification.append('<div class="NotificationTitle">'+title+'</div>');
    $thisNotification.append('<div class="NotificationDescription">'+description+'</div>');
    $(".NotificationDescription").hide();

    $thisNotification.click(function()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
        $('.NotificationDescription').slideToggle('slow');
    });
}
```

How can I get the `.NotificationDescription` to be uniquely recognized for each notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the `.children()` method:  [jQuery docs for children method](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
$thisNotification.click(function()
{
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded').children('.NotificationDescription').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: You actually already use this technique when you load a single notification object based on the title attribute.  I just noticed that!

Comment: It just goes to show how much I don't know what I'm doing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just find the right one for the clicked element:

```
$thisNotification.click(function()
{
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
    $(this).find('.NotificationDescription').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

You can chain the calls if you like:

```
$thisNotification.click(function()
{
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded').find('.NotificationDescription').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try out event delegations.

```
$('#NotificationContainer > div.Notification').live('click',function()
{ 
$(this).toggleClass('expanded').find('div.NotificationDescription').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

This way you only need to attach the event once (on init), and a single event handles all the notifications.

You also should add all your html at one time:

```
var $NotificationContainer = $("#NotificationContainer");
var $Notification = $('<div class="Notification" title="'+title+'"></div>');
$Notification.append('<div class="NotificationTitle">'+title+'</div>');
$Notification.append('<div class="NotificationDescription">'+description+'</div>');
$NotificationContainer.append($Notification);
```

notice the subtle difference, we're building the elements in jquery rather than the dom, and append them all at once.